# Create PowerShell variable for a directory

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I'm trying to create a variable that would be a directory location.
I want to be able to do two things with it, list or change to a directory using the variable, or reference it as a path when executing a command. For example, I'd like to be able to do something like this (which is similar to how I'd do it in Unix):

```
>$dr = "E:\Program Files (x86)\Faasoft\Video Converter\"
>ls $dr
>$dr/ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi output.mp4
```

This syntax doesn't work, nor do any of the variations I've tried with parentheses or braces. I have a number of varied directories with commands I want to run, but I do not want to add all of them to my path.

How can I accomplish this in PowerShell?

Comment: "This syntax doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  What happens when you try it?  Does it produce an error?  Does it change to the wrong directory?  `ls $dr` should definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually pretty sure this is a duplicate of something somewhere, but since I can't search in SO for `&`, here's one way to do it:

```
& "$dr/ffmpeg.exe" -i input.avi output.mp4
```

However, I would recommend using single-quotes when initializing `$dr` to avoid any unexpected interpolation.

```
$dr = 'E:\Program Files (x86)\Faasoft\Video Converter\'
& "$dr/ffmpeg.exe" -i input.avi output.mp4
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate that I could find as I searched extensively for this use case but couldn't find it.  However, your method works great, thank you!  So, what's the protocol now.  Do I accept the answer or wait for others to add comments?

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, feel free to accept it.  You can always change to a different answer later if someone posts a better one.